# Change ul li to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna change actual ul li to select option in my template. In original script I use ul li tags, but for new template I need change it to select option. Original code look like this:

```js
$('#line li').click(function() {
 var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
 if ($(this).index() > 0) {
  if (parentClass == 'time') {
   var data = $(this).attr('data-formVar');
   $('#form_'+parentClass).val(data);
   $('.'+parentClass+' li.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
  } else if (parentClass == 'genre') {
   var data = $(this).attr('data-formVar'),
    formVarElement = $('#form_'+parentClass);
   if (data == '') {
    formVarElement.val('');
    $('.'+parentClass+' li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
   } else {
    $(this).parent().children().eq(1).removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
     $(this).removeClass('active');
     genreSelection[$(this).index() - 1] = 0;
    } else {
     $(this).addClass('active');
     genreSelection[$(this).index() - 1] = 1;
    }
    var toPaste = '';
    $.each(genreSelection, function(key, value) {
     if (value == 1) {
      toPaste += key+',';
     }
    });
    formVarElement.val(toPaste);
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=-1">Yesterday<br /><span class="date">05.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li class = "active"><a href="?page=homepage&day=0">Today<br /><span class="date">06.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=1">Tomorrow<br /><span class="date">07.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=2">Friday<br /><span class="date">08.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=3">Saturday<br /><span class="date">09.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=4">Sunday<br /><span class="date">10.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=5">Monday<br /><span class="date">11.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=6">Tuesday<br /><span class="date">12.04.2016</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="?page=homepage&day=7">Wednesday<br /><span class="date">13.04.2016</span></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="line">
<ul class="time">
<li class="active" data-formVar="now"><a href="#">Right now</a></li>
<li  data-formVar="day"><a href="#">All day</a></li>
<li  data-formVar="evening"><a href="#">Evening</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="genre">
<li class="active"  data-formVar=""><a href="#">All</a></li>
<li data-formVar="1"><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
<li data-formVar="2"><a href="#">Serials</a></li>
<li data-formVar="3"><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li data-formVar="4"><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
<li data-formVar="5"><a href="#">Document</a></li>
<li data-formVar="6"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is my new HTML template with javascript. I changed ul li to select option in script and removed div id "line" in template. But script is not working. And I don't know why. If I click on select and choose any option it will reload page without effect.

```js
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
 var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('selected','selected');
 if ($(this).index() > 0) {
  if (parentClass == 'time') {
   var data = $(this).attr('data-formVar');
   $('#form_'+parentClass).val(data);
   $('.'+parentClass+' option:selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
  } else if (parentClass == 'genre') {
   var data = $(this).attr('data-formVar'),
    formVarElement = $('#form_'+parentClass);
   if (data == '') {
    formVarElement.val('');
    $('.'+parentClass+' option:selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
   } else {
    $(this).parent().children().eq(1).removeClass('selected');
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
     $(this).removeClass('selected');
     genreSelection[$(this).index() - 1] = 0;
    } else {
     $(this).addClass('selected');
     genreSelection[$(this).index() - 1] = 1;
    }
    var toPaste = '';
    $.each(genreSelection, function(key, value) {
     if (value == 1) {
      toPaste += key+',';
     }
    });
    formVarElement.val(toPaste);
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="btn1">
<div class="days">
<select>
<option value=""><a href="#">Yesterday - 07.08</a></option>
<option value="" selected="selected"><a href="#">Today - 07.08</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Tomorrov - 07.08</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Thursday - 07.08</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Friday - 07.08</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Saturday - 07.08</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Sunday - 07.08</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Monday - 07.08</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Tuesday - 07.08</a></option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="btn2">
<div class="menu">
<h3>Kdy</h3>
<select>
<option value="" selected="selected">Right know</option>
<option value="">All day</option>
<option value="">Evening</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="btn3"> 
<div class="menu_second">
<h2>Genre</h2>
<select>
<option value="" selected="selected"><a href="#">All</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Movies</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Serial</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">News</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Sport</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Document</a></option>
<option value=""><a href="#">Other</a></option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: unable to get what your actual question is, your subject says ul>li to select box, which you have did already, what actually needed?

Comment: Script is not working. After click on select option page is just reload. Without effect.

Comment: __without effect__ without what effect?

Comment: You are switching on class names that don't exist anymore. so your if-else-if block is getting skipped over